# Append data from numerous source google sheets to single target master google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I have a master sheet, and n number of marketing profile sheets spread out around different sales personnel. (data in the sheet are customer name and mobile number).

I have my master sheet's URL available. Profile sheets could be replicated by the personnel and hence no fixed URL data available.
I need to embed a macro into the marketing profile sheet that would append a fixed range of data (name and number) from the profile sheet to my master data, given my master data URL is available (`importrange` won't work).

Is there any workaround??

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N9d0u0Z-o6WVXfwDR6tZQ3_t2LqnRiv1ijAYAj1oNCc/edit?usp=sharing         -- Link to master sheet ..    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBQA64ofstNKHLg_keOP_6b5-tJ8WsAQKCTw8OOfHKA/edit?usp=sharing    --- Link to lead tracker 1 .....      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dn02JG8J6ro6nLhlc6yHvDzJGxGW1pvw8K5nLBgwZqw/edit?usp=sharing  -- Link to lead tracker 2. There are n other lead trackers spread out with various employees. I have inserted master tracker link in all the  lead sheets too.

Comment: All the leads would have to do is run a prefixed macro that would access the master sheet link attached and append the required data.